# Clear a field, iff content not equal to a specific string

Tags: biblatex

I am attempting to clear a BibLaTeX field via the usual `\DeclareSourcemap` construct, as explained in [§4.5.3](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Specifically, the following works correctly for me in most cases, resulting in `pubstate` being cleared:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
      \step[fieldset=pubstate, null]
  }
}
```

I want, however, for entries containing the particular `pubstate`, `\bibstring{submitted}`, to *not* get cleared, but for all others (e.g. those with `pubstate = {\bibstring{prepublished}}`) to indeed be cleared.

Ignoring the `bibstring` complexity for now (though I have also attempted when including it and in my present case it simply becomes "Submitted"), I have tried the following, without success:

```
\step[fieldset=pubstate, notmatch=\regexp{[Ss]ubmitted}, null]
```

Adding `.*` prefixes and suffixes to the above regular expression, or adding and removing groupings, also appears ineffective. I also tried to get this to work with various combinations of `match` and `replace`, with and without multiple `\step` commands, or instead working via `fieldsource`.

Might someone please suggest how I can best accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`match` is documented in the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), p. 178, as

> If `match` is defined but `replace` is not, only apply the step if the
>   `fieldsource` `<entryfield>` matches the `match` regular expression (logic is
>   reversed if you use `notmatch` instead).

So a `match` needs a `fieldsource` and not a `fieldset`. That means that your one-liner can't work and needs to be expanded to a two-liner

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=pubstate, notmatch={[sS]ubmitted}, final]
      \step[fieldset=pubstate, null]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author   = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title    = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date     = {1980},
  pubstate = {prepublished},
}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  pubstate  = {submitted},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{elk,appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Appleby, Humphrey (1980). On the Importance of the Civil Service.//Elk, Anne (1972). A Theory on Brontosauruses. Submitted.]

Future versions of `biblatex` and Biber will have a case-insensitive `notmatchi` that avoids the `[sS]`: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/235

Note that it is not necessary to use `\bibstring` within the `pubstate` field, it will be added automatically if necessary by `biblatex` when the field is printed.