# Automatic symbol annotation, for annotated BibLaTeX author lists

Tags: biblatex

I am using annotated BibLaTeX author lists (`author+an`), as discussed in a [prior question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468623) and as [recently-integrated](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/853) into BibLaTeX sub-commands (e.g., `\mkbibcompletename`).

I want to automatically produce an amended author list, which includes daggers for co-first authors, and asterisks for co-corresponding authors.

For example, the below BibLaTeX entry, should produce the below annotated author list in its full reference, with superscript dagger/asterisk symbols (formatting not shown), as a part of its full citation. Existing annotations, such as the presently-included asterisks after the first two listed authors, should also be removed and ignored.

```
@Article{         scott:beyond,
  author        = {Mastromatteo, Scott * and Viner, Coby * and Denisko, Danielle and
                   Negrea, Jeffrey and Tang, Yanbo and Zhang, Lin and Hoffman,
                   Michael M. and Sun, Lei},
  author+an     = {1=jointfirst; 2=jointfirst;
                   2=jointcorresponding; 7=jointcorresponding; 8=jointcorresponding},
  title         = {Beyond statistical significance: ranking transcription
                   factor binding motifs by effect size},
  year          = {2023},
  month         = {4},
%  doi      = {10.1101/XXXXXX},
%  journal  = {{bioRxiv}},
%  pages    = {0XXXXX},
  pubstate      = {\bibstring{inpreparation}},
  note          = {Manuscript draft available upon request.},
  addendum      = {doctoral work}
}
```

Mastromatteo, S†, Viner, C†*, Denisko, D, Negrea, J, Tang, Y, Zhang, L, Hoffman, MM*, Sun, L*, 2023. Beyond statistical significance: ranking transcription factor binding motifs by effect size. Manuscript draft available upon request. In preparation.

---

I do not currently have an attempt at doing this, as the present parsing and ability to make use of these author annotations, in BibLaTeX macros, is not clear to me. I would quite appreciate answers including some explanation or references on this topic.

At present, I perform other processing of references, as shown below, into which these requested modifications would ideally integrate:

```
% some adaptations from: http://www.khirevich.com/latex/biblatex/

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{ % journal names to shorter names, if existing
      \step[fieldsource=shortjournal] % e.g. Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. U.S.A.
      %\step[fieldsource=shortestjournal] % e.g. PNAS; use to also map to shortest names, if existing
      \step[fieldset=journaltitle, origfieldval]
    }
    %
    \map{ % book/conference names to short names
      \step[fieldsource=shortbook]
      \step[fieldset=booktitle, origfieldval]
    }
    \map{
      % suppress the following fields
      \step[fieldset=month, null]
      \step[fieldset=eventdate, null]
      \step[fieldset=publisher, null]
      \step[fieldset=editor, null]  % N.B. no editor for now...
      %
      % do not clear, if submitted
      % From: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453744/134641
      % N.B. The below must be at the end of this map statement, as the below
      %       use of "final" will terminate this map, if notmatch is SAT.
      %
      % XXX N.B. Now keeping all pubstates, as demarcating pre-published from in-prep.
      %
      %\step[fieldsource=pubstate, notmatch={[sS]ubmitted}, final]
      %\step[fieldset=pubstate, null]
     }
     \map{  % suppress the following field(s), except for presentations
       \pernottype{inproceedings}
       \expandafter\step[fieldset=addendum, null] % suppress NSERC education segment designations
     }
     \map{  % NSERC doesn't want numbers, but we still include it for patents
       \pernottype{patent}
       \step[fieldset=number, null]
     }
     \map{
       \pertype{patent}
       %
       % clear patent scope, obviating output of redundant info. for US patents
       \step[fieldset=location, null]
       %
       % we include the USPTO kind codes, but do not use them
       \step[fieldset=kind, null]
       %
       % we use the field "appnumber" to store the USPTO application number
       % we simply map it to be appended to the "type" field, in the standard data model
       % ------------------------------------------------------------
       % "terrible hack"; used for now, in favour of custom DBX definition
       % From: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454143/134641
       %
       \step[fieldsource=appnumber, final]
       %
       % also save this in userf, to permit external use
       \step[fieldset=userf, origfieldval]
       %
       \step[fieldsource=type, match=\regexp{\A(.*)\Z}, replace=\regexp{\\ifbibstring\{$1\}\{\\bibstring\{$1\}\}\{$1\}\x{20}}]
       \step[fieldsource=appnumber]
       \step[fieldset=type, origfieldval, append]
       % ------------------------------------------------------------
     }
    % map citation count fields to user-defined fields, to permit usage
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=citecount]
      \step[fieldset=usera, origfieldval]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=citecountNS]
      \step[fieldset=userb, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

% TODO the below fails, but something like this would be nice
%\DeclareDataInheritance{patent}{patent}{
%    % map the parent's appnumber (in userf) to the child's usere
%    \inherit[override]{userf}{usere}
%}

% ------------------------------------------------------------
% Patch the BibLaTeX output for @Patent entries:
%    add punctuation, after the "type" field.
%
\xpatchbibdriver{patent}%
   {\printfield{type}\setunit*{\addspace}}%
   {\printfield{type}\setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}}{}{}
% ------------------------------------------------------------

% custom citation command to output paper citation information
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citationscite}{}{Cited $\thefield{usera}$ times ($\thefield{userb}$, strictly non-self; per \href{https://scholar.google.ca/citations?user=RUrFz2oAAAAJ}{Google Scholar}).}{}{}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  patrequs = {US patent application}  % "application", not "request"; no dots in "US"
}

% italisize the book's title for @inproceedings entries
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{booktitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
% remove volume indication (i.e. vol.) before volume numbers for @inproceedings entries
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
%------------------------------------------------
% Apply page range compression
% From: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25374

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkcomprange{#1}}

% Compress ranges where lower limit > 100
\setcounter{mincomprange}{100}

% Don't compress beyond the fourth digit
\setcounter{maxcomprange}{1000}

% Display compressed upper limit with at least two digits,
% unless leading digit is zero
\setcounter{mincompwidth}{10}
%--------------------------------------
```

---

No Minimal Working Example (MWE) is provided at this time. I am seeking a general solution to this issue. Should no solution be provided after some time, I will try to compose a proper MWE. Apologies for any inconvenience and thanks in advance for your kind assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the answer I will assume that the `author` field does not contain any additional markup like `*`.

Note that if you want to pass multiple annotations to one list item, you have to use

```
<item no>=<annotation_1>, <annotation_2>, ..., <annotation_n>;
```

and not `<item no>=<annotation_1>; <item_no>=<annotation_2>; ...; <item no>=<annotation_n>;`. In the latter form only the last annotation survives. (An example of this and the format syntax can be found in §3.7 *Data Annotations* of [the `biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), specifically p. 85.)

Then you can use code similar to the one suggested in your links.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
    ##1%
    \ifitemannotation{jointfirst}{\dag}{}%
    \ifitemannotation{jointcorresponding}{*}{}}%
  #1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{scott:beyond,
  author        = {Mastromatteo, Scott and Viner, Coby and Denisko, Danielle and
                   Negrea, Jeffrey and Tang, Yanbo and Zhang, Lin and Hoffman,
                   Michael M. and Sun, Lei},
  author+an     = {1=jointfirst; 2=jointfirst, jointcorresponding;
                   7=jointcorresponding; 8=jointcorresponding},
  title         = {Beyond statistical significance: ranking transcription
                   factor binding motifs by effect size},
  year          = {2023},
  month         = {4},
  pubstate      = {\bibstring{inpreparation}},
  note          = {Manuscript draft available upon request.},
  addendum      = {doctoral work},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,scott:beyond}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Mastromatteo, Scott†, Coby Viner†, Danielle Denisko, Jeffrey Negrea, Yanbo Tang, Lin Zhang, Michael M. Hoffman and Lei Sun*]

---

If we have to clean the `author` field of unwanted markup first, I suggest a sourcemap. There is always a risk that you have bona fide uses of `*` in names in  your `.bib` files that this sourcemap would clear out, that's why I prefer to keep the data clean in the first place (plus the sourcemap has a small impact on performance), but if you insist, this is probably the quickest solution.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[foreach=setnames]{
      \step[fieldsource=\regexp{$MAPLOOP}, 
        match=\regexp{\s+\*},
        replace={}]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
    ##1%
    \ifitemannotation{jointfirst}{\dag}{}%
    \ifitemannotation{jointcorresponding}{*}{}}%
  #1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{scott:beyond,
  author        = {Mastromatteo, Scott * and Viner, Coby * and Denisko, Danielle and
                   Negrea, Jeffrey and Tang, Yanbo and Zhang, Lin and Hoffman,
                   Michael M. and Sun, Lei},
  author+an     = {1=jointfirst; 2=jointfirst, jointcorresponding;
                   7=jointcorresponding; 8=jointcorresponding},
  title         = {Beyond statistical significance: ranking transcription
                   factor binding motifs by effect size},
  year          = {2023},
  month         = {4},
  pubstate      = {\bibstring{inpreparation}},
  note          = {Manuscript draft available upon request.},
  addendum      = {doctoral work},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,scott:beyond}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```